# Creation failed with Flutter code Obfuscating

Tags: flutter, dart

I am following this guide: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate

Running Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable

When I run:

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/sample/debug --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
```

Then I get the following error:

```
    Target android_aot_release_android-arm failed: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path =
 '/sample' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)
    Target android_aot_release_android-x64 failed: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 
'/sample' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)
    Target android_aot_release_android-arm64 failed: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 
'/sample' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)
    build failed.                                                           
                                                                            
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                            
    * Where:                                                                
    Script '/Users/user/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 882
                                                                            
    * What went wrong:                                                      
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.            
    > Process 'command '/Users/user/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
                                                                            
    * Try:                                                                  
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get 
more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                            
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Where is the `/sample` located?

Answer (score 7):

You should provide a relative path from your root:

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./sample/debug
```